# How do I get Google to display a section called "Latest from example.com" for my site?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, rich-cards

I would like Google to display the latest articles from my website in a special section when you search for my site.

As an example CNN gets such a section in the results:

[image]

Comment: I bet you are talking about Google News: https://news.google.com. Check if you can use it cause some countries has restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display the latest articles in the special section on Google when people search for your site, you need to have a structured data set for your articles. A proper guideline can be found at: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article

Comment: Is article structured data enough?  I'm sure CNN is also a Google news partner, and I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it.   I'd also think site reputation would factor in, just like it does for site links.

Comment: Structured data is a pre-requisite and mandatory. Other factors in Google's Algo may include: 
1) Quality of the article
2) The freshness of the content
3) Traffic to that particular page
4) User Behavior - Stats like CTR, time on page etc
5) Authority of the website
6) The popularity of the website